# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "return" y "exit" en Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Revisando código de un shell script, he visto que se hizo un cambio en una línea:

> Nota: si el código contiene errores es porque he quitado cosas intentando reducirlo a lo mínimo para ilustrar la pregunta. El código original funciona correctamente.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Error: se necesita al menos un argumento"
  exit 1     # originariamente "return 1"
fi

return 0
```

El `exit 1` originalmente era un `return 1`. No termino de comprender por qué se cambió el `return 1` por un `exit 1`, pero no el `return 0` por un `exit 0`. ¿Habría alguna diferencia entre los dos en este caso?

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `return` y `exit` en Bash? ¿Y cuándo debería usarse cada uno?

Comment: Además, ¿cómo estás ejecutando el script? El `return` solamente se puede utilizar desde dentro de una función o cuando usas `source`, tal y como indica la consola si se ejecuta tu script con, por ejemplo,  `./script.sh foo` ---> `line 8: return: can only 'return' from a function or sourced script`.

Comment: La cabecera es `/bin/sh` pero luego hablas de Bash. El comportamiento es distinto si usas Bash o si usas la shell POSIX. Clarifica por favor para poder ofrecer una respuesta al respecto.

Comment: @fedorqui actualicé la pregunta para especificar bash. El script se ejecuta a través de Jenkins, tendría que ver el log para ver exactamente cómo o los mensajes que lanza.

Comment: ¿ Podrias *des-aceptar* mi respuesta ? @fedorqui tiene razón, y en la doc. de *Bash* así se indica. Por algún motivo que ignoro, en mi sistema no ocurre lo que debería, pero parece claro que es un comportamiento erróneo, y una respuesta incorrecta.

Comment: Sería bueno cambiar la aceptación de la respuesta o bien que @Trauma actualice su respuesta según lo comentado.

Comment: @fedorqui Si Alvaro cambia el `aceptado`, con gusto la elimino. Si está mal, está mal. Y la tuya es mejor respuesta :-)

Comment: @Trauma  Lo que me preocupa es que "cale" una respuesta no del todo correcta. Por mí ningún problema en que cojas todo lo necesario de mi respuesta, en serio :)

Comment: @fedorqui ¿ Para que queremos 2 respuestas con lo mismo ? Nada nada, quito esta y dejamos la tuya, que, como digo, es mucho *mas mejor* respuesta :-) A ver si Alvaro aparece ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Bash, un `return` solamente se puede usar dentro de una función o en un archivo al que vamos a hacer `source`. En estos casos, tiene el mismo valor que `exit`, consistente en salir y devolver un código de estado que se puede recoger con `$?`.

---

En tu código, pues, lo correcto sería que ambos `return` hubieran sido convertidos en `exit`, pues actualmente el script no funcionaría bien. En particular, si lo ejecutamos con un argumento nos devuelve el error:

> ```
> line 8: return: can only 'return' from a function or sourced script
> ```

---

Contrariamente a lo que ocurre en otros lenguajes, Bash no tiene un `return` al uso para utilizar en las funciones. Es así por la propia esencia del uso de pipes: un comando devuelve contenido al siguiente. De este modo, lo que se hace es devolver a través de, por ejemplo, un `echo` y luego recogerlo ejecutando el comando con `$()`:

```
function dame_tu_edad() {
   read edad
   echo "$edad"
}

tu_edad=$(dame_tu_edad)
echo "tu edad es $tu_edad"
```

La [especificación POSIX de `return`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_24_03) nos advierte:

> La utilidad [`return`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#return) hará que la shell deje de ejecutar la función actual o el script [dot](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot). Si la shell no está ejecutando actualmente una función o un script [dot](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot), los resultados no están especificados.
>
> <sub>(traducción mía esta y las siguientes)</sub>

Por lo que Bash tomó la decisión de que un `return` no funcione fuera de una función o de script dot (es decir, al hacer un `source`). Otras shells usan otros métodos ([referencia](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230695/40596)).

---

En Bash, `return` y `exit` son sinónimas, tal y como se explica en [Bash Reference Manual → Definitions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Definitions):

> `exit status` El valor devuelto por un comando a quien lo llamó. El valor está restringido a ocho bits, por lo que el máximo es 255.
>
> `return status` Sinónimo de `exit status`.

Más adelante explica en [Shell functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions):

> Si el comando builtin `return` se ejecuta en una función, la función se da por concluida y la ejecución continúa con el siguiente comando después de la llamada a la función. (...) Si se da un parámetro numérico a `return`, ese es el estado de retorno de la función; si no, el estado de `return` de la función es el código de retorno del último comando ejecutado antes del `return`.

---

Algunos ejemplos:

```
function hola() {
   return 23
}

hola
echo $?   # devuelve 23
```

Ejecutando esto tenemos que `$?` tiene valor 23.